# Associate GitLab group with a specific email

Tags: gitlab

In GitLab I am signed up with my personal email, and also added a company email. Then I have created a group relating to that company. Currently when I complete a merge request it always goes under my personal email, instead of the company email. Is there any way to associate a specific email address to a specific group in GitLab?

Comment: See [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/21). It may helps you.

Comment: Thanks. That page describe the work done when they added email aliases which is the screen I am using to add a secondary email address for work. Now the problem is that when I complete a merge request, the email used for that (which shows up in Git history) is using my personal email and not my work email.